# Java: error: Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method accept(Visitor). While implementing Visitor

Tags: java, design-patterns, compiler-errors, visitor-pattern

I'm trying to implement a Visitor design pattern, I have a class structure with a lot of classes and variable return types between the operation I want to do with the visitor.

I am getting a lot of the compile error `Classname is not abstract and does not override abstract method accept(Visitor) in Visitable` despite having followed the visitor pattern strictly.

For example my class Add

```
public class Add extends BinaryExpression implements Visitable {
 /* content of the class supressed */
   public Integer accept(Visitor v) {
      return v.visit(this); 
    }        
}
```

In the case of the visitor for the Add class it will always return int, but the visitor for some other classes will return other types or even variable types within the same class.

On my visitable interface I have (Using generic types for the variable return types.)

```
public interface Visitable<T> {
  public T accept(Visitor v);}
```

On my visitor Interface I have

```
public interface Visitor<T> {
  public T visit(Add c);
```

My Evaluator Visitor

```
public class Evaluator<T> implements Visitor{ 
  public Integer visitAdd(Add c){
    return c.first().accept(this) + c.second().accept(this);
  }
```

Screenshot of the full error
[image: error]

Updated error screen
[image: updated error screen]

Comment: I believe it's because you're not supplying a generic type when you implement visitable. For example, I think it should be _implements Visitable<Integer>_.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem unfortunately. Getting the exact same error

Answer (score 2):

The error is because `int` is primitive not an `Object` type unlike an `Integer`. In other words, 
Generic types accept only object reference types, but not primitives, so change your `accept(Visitor v)` method return type to `Integer` so that it will compile:

```
public class Add extends BinaryExpression implements Visitable {
   public Integer accept(Visitor v) {
      return v.visit(this); 
    }        
}
```

Comment: No, this particular `accept(Visitor v)` implementation returns `Integer` object, but `Visitable` can still be generic

Comment: Ok, this solved a lot of my problems, I wasn't aware of that, however a error still stands `./Add.java:32: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Integer
      return v.visitAdd(this); 
                      `

Comment: Just did it, I also tried  with `implements Visitable<Integer>` with no success

Comment: Now, the problem is with your Visitor implementation (object passed to accept()) which is returning Object

Comment: @javaguy I added the simplified Visitor interface and Visitor code above.  The problem is, I have 2 visitors which run through a number of classes, one of them is similar to a toString which will always return a String, the other is Evaluator which will return a int, boolean, string, depending on the operation. I tried using generic types in the Visitor interface to avoid creating 2 different visitor interfaces.

Comment: I could not see any method above which is shown in the compilation error which is `v.visitAdd(this)` ? Where is that code ?